# how to get url parameter and pass to proxy_pass using nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I need to get the parameter from an URL, for example, abc=MY_STRING:

```
https://my-address/test?abc=MY_STRING
```

And at the reverse proxy (my-address), is configured like this:

```
location /test?(.*) {
  proxy_pass http://local-server:1234/test?$args
}
```

but it is not working.

I tried another configuration:

```
location /test?(.*) {
  proxy_pass http://local-server:1234/test?$1
}
```

but not worked too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot match the query string part of the URI with a `location` or `rewrite` statement, as it is not part of the [normalized URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

But you don't need to. The URI (complete with query string) will be passed upstream
unless you redirect it using a `rewrite` or `try_files` statement.

For example:

```
location /test {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
}
```

The URI `/test?abc=MY_STRING` will match the location and be passed to `localhost:1234` exactly the same. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for more.

Comment: It works after I remove try_files from location block. Thank you.